# The output remains the same

Tags: linux, bash

The output remains **"Dead,ciao in hell"** irrespective of the input.

```
<---Begin Code--->
echo "Which wire to cut? Red or Green? "
read die
if [[ die = "red" ]]; then
echo "You are saved!"
else echo "Dead,ciao in hell"
fi
<---End COde--->
```

Can somebody pleas help me?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/# helps in catching such typos...

Answer (score 2):

You missed the **$** symbol at die

```
echo "Which wire to cut? Red or Green? "
read die
if [[ $die = "red" ]]; then
echo "You are saved!"
else echo "Dead,ciao in hell"
fi
```

**OutPut**

```
Which wire to cut? Red or Green? 
asd
Dead,ciao in hell
Which wire to cut? Red or Green? 
red
You are saved!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize user input. Say, what if he typed `reD` in panic? He is still saved?

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p  "Which wire to cut? Red or Green?" die
die="${die:-GREEN}" # if the die's value is null, set it to GREEN
die="${die^^}" # Convert the input to uppercase
if [ "$die" = "RED" ]
then
  echo "You are saved!"
elif [ "$die" = "GREEN" ]
then
  echo "Dead,ciao in hell"
else
  echo "Confused, you deserve to die"
fi
```

**Improvements**

- Used `read prompt` with the `-p` option
- Added a null-value check for `die` and set defaults to 'GREEN' using `die="${die:-GREEN}"`
- Added  `elif-else` part to deal with with input which is other than expected value.
- Since the input is preprocessed, replaced `[[..]]` with built-in `[..]`.